# Increase varchar limit fot small_image attribute

Tags: magento2.3, importexport, magento2.3.4, varchar

I am using Magento 2.3.4.I have imported the product sheet in back end. 
It throws the error "Attribute small_image exceeded max length in row(s): 1".I have to import image from external url  the image url length is so long.I have to increase the length only for small_image.

Comment: If my answer works for you could you check it as correct answer or upvote it @Jothi

Answer (score 0):

Use type `TEXT` instead of `VARCHAR`